# How to access JS variable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have

```
<div id="blah">500</div>
```

(Context: asp.net aspx page) 
How do I allow a c# code access that value?

```
<%
    int numberiwant = ###; // Ideally 500
%>
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var value = $('#blah').html();
// Then do some magic and pass to c#?
</script>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Update: the issue is that the content inside the blah div is populated using AJAX, so I have no pre-page-population control over the content.

Comment: In that case, you also need AJAX to send these contents to the server.

Comment: See my answer for a potential option. If you want a more AJAX like option, let us know more about your scenario and what you are trying to accomplish. An extremely simple ajax way would be to have a hidden iframe, and set the url with the value in the query string. But if you already are using AJAX, tell us what framework you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a hidden input box

```
<input id="hiddenControl" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Put your value in the input box with javascript

```
//call this method before you postback, maybe on form submit
function SetPostbackValues() {
  var hiddenControl = '<%= hiddenControl.ClientID %>';
  document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = 500; 
  //or some other code to get your value
}
```

Access the value with the input box on the server side

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   var hiddenValue = hiddenControl.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a server-side div instead, like i.e;

```
<asp:Panel ID="blah" runat="server">500</asp:Panel>
```

Then you can access it and its contents server-side.

Alternatively;

```
<div id="blah"><asp:Literal ID="blahContent" runat="server" Text="500" /></div>
```

UPDATE: After the question was clarified, it is clear this won't work. The only solution then is to use javascript to get the value, then AJAX to send it to the server.

Comment: You can also add the runat="server" directly to the div.

Comment: I don't have control over the content of the div as I generate the page.

Answer (score 1):

The C# code inside `<% .. %>` is run on the server when the HTML is generated. When the value updates via AJAX, it all happens on the client - long after the C# has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

Server side won't ever have direct access to client's variables (javascript). You have to send them to the server somehow, either via query or post, or through AJAX.