# Javascript read public variable from c# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#

Trying to use public properties from C# code behind and want to read the variable value from a JavaScript function

JavaScript function:

```
function IsAgentInProgram()
{
    var optStatus = "<%=AgentOptInStatus%>";

    if (optStatus == "True")
        alert("You are opted in!");
    else
        alert ("You are opted OUT");
}
```

C# code behind

```
public bool AgentOptInStatus;

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.AgentOptInStatus = true;

}
```

This does not work. Output comes back as `You are opted OUT`. I also did an alert on `optStatus` and it comes back with: `"<%=AgentOptInStatus%>"`

Am I missing something?

Comment: you can set to input the prop value and read it with js.

Comment: @RA19 this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465732/how-to-access-js-variable-in-c-sharp javascript is client side and c# is server side pretty big difference in variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the client side variables directly in the codebehind. What you can do is creating a hidden field and setting the value with javascript, then you can read it in c#.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var somefunction = function () {
            var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById('hdnfldVariable');
            hdnfldVariable.value = 'value from javascript';
        }
    </script>
```

c# :

```
string selected = hdnfldVariable.Value.ToString();
```

Another option is to make an HTTP request to the server to call a function from a controller passing the data as parameters.